# Adding an on click event to an Annotation in pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, annotations

I'm looking for a way to add an "on click" event to an annotation in `matplotlib.pyplot` to destroy it. The relevant code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot()
plt.annotate("Kill me",xy=(0,0))
```

Now we need to find the annotation, one way is to iterate over:

```
plt.gca().texts
```

Though there may be a better way. So far I have not found how to obtain the widget/add an event with this. This may be possible using `mpl_connect` of the `plt` figure canvas but I'm not sure, and that would require going by the bounding box, which I would like to avoid, but if no other is solution is available is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed use [`mpl_connect`](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) to connect a picker event to an object in the canvas. In this case the call to `annotate` can be given a `picker` argument, which specifies the radius around the object that should trigger the event.

You can then directly operate on the object that triggered the event, which is available in the event slot as `event.artist`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot([0,5],[0,6], alpha=0)
plt.xlim([-1,6])
plt.ylim([-1,6])

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        an = plt.annotate("Kill me",xy=(j,i), picker=5)


def onclick(event):
    event.artist.set_text("I'm killed")
    event.artist.set_color("g")
    event.artist.set_rotation(20)
    # really kill the text (but too boring for this example;-) )
    #event.artist.set_visible(False) 
    # or really REALLY kill it with:
    #event.artist.remove()
    fig.canvas.draw()


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Awesome! Could you clarify the meaning of the `picker` flag? It needs to be a positive integer to work with "pick_event" as far as I could tell, but why 5? Also I added a slight update.

Comment: NM read about it in the docs. I suggest you add it for future reference though. Thanks again!

Comment: Edit approved. The `picker` argument specifies the radius around the object that should trigger the event, but can also simply be set to `1` or `True` (which is equavalent).